# jQuery prevent default, form submit twice

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to prevent a form to submit twice after changing a select box. I tried to use e.preventDefault(), but it makes no difference.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on("change","#select1", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#form1").submit();
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The form won't submit twice with that code, but it does'nt prevent the form from submitting either, it just prevents the change event on the select, as that is the element and event you are binding to.

Comment: But what could it be than that is submitting the form twice? Hitting the submit button doesn't fire submit twice.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var changed = 0;
    $(document).on("change","#select1", function(e)
    {
        changed++;
        if( changed > 1)
            return false;

        $("#form1").submit();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `preventDefault` on the form's submit event:

```
$('form').live('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```